# SwiftUI on MacOS: How do I fix the window size

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I seem to be missing something basic:

I have a window with a sidebar. The nested hierarchy is

```
ZStack {
  NavigationView {
     VStack {
        //additional sub-views with my content/navigation view
     }.frame(...)
  }.frame(...)
}
```

When the window opens, everything is fine - my sidebar is the right size, the rest of the main window is fine. I just don't want someone to resize the window to the right (i.e. expanding it horizontally).

I've tried `.frame(width: ..., height: ...)`, I've tried `.frame(minWidth: ...)`, I've tried `.fixedSize()` - it doesn't matter, I'm still able to expand the window horizontally.

What could I be missing or what should I look for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to set your maxWidth on the containing ZStack.

```swift
ZStack {
...
}.frame(maxWidth: 600)
```

Comment: Dang, that was it. I kept wondering what was I missing - I had to move the maxWidth outermost. The inner frame maxWidth wasn't working. Thank you. I'll mark answer when it lets me.